# Draw a frequency plot in d3 with JSON data

Tags: json, graph, d3.js, frequency-distribution

I am doing a project in d3 and am at my wits' end on how to draw a frequency graph for graphing tweets. So, basically, I have a JSON file whose format is like this

```
{
    "text": "some text here",
    "time": "timestamp here",
    "timezone": "timezone here",
    "retweet_count": some number,
    "hashtags": "some text here"
}
```

So, now I need to draw a graph in d3 which shows the number of tweets in a particular time period. For example, between date X and date Y, the graph shows how many tweets were there per day.

Can someone help me out with this? I'm really very new to d3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the [d3 time scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales) together with the [intervals](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Intervals) to do your binning for you. Something like:

```
var data= [
  {time: 'Jan. 1, 2012 13:00', name:"test", value:2},
  {time: 'Jan. 2, 2012 9:00', name:"test", value:2},
  {time: 'Jan. 3, 2012 14:00', name:"test", value:2},
  {time: 'Jan. 1, 2012 12:30', name:"test", value:2},
  {time: 'Jan. 3, 2012 1:00', name:"test", value:2},
  {time: 'Jan. 3, 2012 1:10', name:"test", value:2},
  {time: 'Jan. 3, 2012 1:20', name:"test", value:2},
  {time: 'Jan. 3, 2012 2:00', name:"test", value:2},
  {time: 'Jan. 1, 2012 3:00', name:"test", value:2},
];

// Get the date range from the data - could also be hardcoded
var dateRange = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return new Date(d.time); });
console.log("Data range", dateRange); // This will output your data's time range

// This will compute time bins
var binner = d3.time.scale();

// Pick the interval I want to bin on
var interval = d3.time.day; // Use hour, or minute, etc.      

// I will compute the number of the time intervals I want  
var allIntervals = interval.range(interval.floor(dateRange[0]), interval.ceil(dateRange[1]));
console.log("Intervals", allIntervals); // This will output an array of all the days/hours/whatever between min and max date

// Input domain mapped to output range
binner.domain([allIntervals[0], allIntervals[allIntervals.length - 1]]);
binner.range([0,allIntervals.length - 1]);

// Make sure we only output integers - important because we will fill an array
binner.interpolate(d3.interpolateRound);

// Empty histogram
var hist = [];
for(var i=0; i < allIntervals.length; i++) hist[i] = 0;

data.forEach(function(d) {
  // Compute the hour index
  var tid = binner(interval.floor(new Date(d.time)));
  console.log("Map " + d.time + " to " + tid);

  if(!hist[tid]) {
    hist[tid] = 1;
  } 
  else { 
    hist[tid]++;
  }
});

// Here is the histogram.
console.log("Hist:",hist);
```

I put it together with a very rudimentary histogram vis [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PcGYx/)

Note you could probably replace the interval.range(...) call with some millisecond math instead to improve performance, but having all the values can be useful if you want to do, say, tooltips, for example.

Comment: You have to use the usual browsers javascript console, jsFiddle does not have a console view of it's own.

Comment: I added this code to draw an axis but the axis doesn't show `var time_axis = d3.svg.axis ()
  .scale (binner);

d3.select ("svg")
  .append ("g")
  .attr ("class", "x axis")
  .attr ("transform", "translate (0, " + 400 + ")")
  .call (time_axis);`

Comment: you are probably not seeing anything because you are translating 400 along y and the svg is only 400 high. Try changing the height of your svg element. The other part is that binner maps to integers - not to pixels. For an axis you will want a scale that has a range of the desired width in pixels. There is a great tutorial on axes [here](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/axes/).

Comment: Now [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PcGYx/6/) how do I shift the bars to the right by 50? I made width and height as 450. And also, shift the graph down?

Comment: You will want to shift just the plot area. So you will want to create an svg group to hold all the bars and set a tranform on that. Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/H3Z9F/).

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for all the help!! :D